# Question about jokes (I don't know if I am an apostate- help)

Tags: practical-islam

Asallahmualaykum warahmatullahi wa barakatuh, I have a few questions about 3 situations about jokes, and whether I am an apostate for each of them.

1) I don't remember whether I smiled or not at a joke against Islam that my friend made. How would I know if I am an apostate for this situation?

2)If someone said that they are a god at video games, and I said "nice" in response. Is that apostasy?

3)If someone said that soandso is a memegod, and I laughed, am I an apostate?

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically any jokes made in view of Islam is a sin. But The two reasons you mentioned are not indicated to Islam, as the person said "He is God at video games", here He just stated that he is a god of video games which is just a fictional thing not related to Islam. Here he referenced the god word to as master. Same goes for the third one.

To clear things up God is not Allah. God is a word for religions other than Islam. In the 99 names of Allah. There isn't a name as the god.

P.S: This is just my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

To say/think a joke/mock Allah or his messenger or his signs is indeed a sign of hypocrisy. This is clearly in surah 9:

The Hypocrites are afraid lest a Surah should be sent down about them, showing them what is (really passing) in their hearts. Say: "Mock ye! But verily Allah will bring to light all that ye fear (should be revealed)." (9:64) If thou dost question them, they declare (with emphasis): "we were only talking idly and in play." Say: "was it at Allah and His, signs and His Messenger that ye were mocking?" (9:65) Make ye no excuses: ye have rejected Faith after ye had accepted it. If We pardon some of you We will punish others amongst you, for that they are in sin. (9:66)

But only Allah knows if you are a hypocrite but it is a sign of hypocrisy.